# How do I induce this Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality in my book,

> Let $0<\alpha < d$, $1<p<q<\infty$, and $\frac{1}{q} +1 = \frac {1}{p} + \frac {\alpha}{d}$. Then
>   $$ \lVert f \ast |\cdot|^{\alpha} \rVert_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^d )} \leq C_{p,q} \lVert f \rVert_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$

But I saw another one,

> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac {f(x)g(y)}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}dxdy
>  \leq C_{\alpha, p, d }\lVert f \rVert_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\lVert g \rVert_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^d)}. $$
>   for all $f \in L^p, g \in L^q,\quad 1<p,q< \infty,\quad \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac {\alpha}{d} = 2$ and  $0<\alpha <d $.

I want to show bottom one but I am failing it.

Comment: I think a direct use of the definition of convolution and Holder Inequality should give you this result, have you tried this already?

Comment: @Zixiao_Liu Oh my days, I'm such an idiot. Thank you so much. I couldn't think about elementary method. Can't I vote here?

Comment: Maybe you would like to print a sketch of proof and admit it as the answer yourself ;)   It is quite lengthy and not interesting, but still a good exercise anyway. LOL